# Fired method on input with other component with event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

its possible to fired event like on example :

```
const Tet = (props) => {

    return (
        <div>
            <label>id:<input onChange= **FIRED RR METHOD** type="text"/></label>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And my component

```
 class TContainer extends React.Component {

 rr(obj, ev) {
        console.log(obja, ev.target.value));    
 }
 render() {
    return (
      <Tet lala={this.state.dataList} rr={this.rr.bind(this)}/>
    )
 }
```

How to call method with event.target.value and passing normal attr.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to propagate props, the easiest way to do it is:

```js
const Tet = ({ onChange }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={onChange} />
    </div>
  )
}

class TetContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(event) {
     console.log(event.target.value)
  }

  render() {
    return <Tet onChange={this.handleChange} />
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <TetContainer />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass custom arguments then pass a new function to onchange which call your `rr` function with your custom arguments like this

```
const Tet = (props) => {

    return (
        <div>
            <label>id:<input onChange={(e) => {props.rr(obj,e)}} type="text"/></label>
        </div>
    );
}
```